# How to secure a data encryption key on the server?

Tags: security, server

I am building a server based web application. For that, I've to store the encryption keys to the server to decrypt the data from the DB. In this situation, what is the best practice to store the security keys? and where to store the keys on the server to avoid hacking.

Comment: Best practise is not to store the keys on the same server.

Comment: The detailed answer to your questions will only come from you identifying what you're actually trying to defend against. Security is not black and white - you have different defences against different types of threat.

Comment: @Martin, but its hardly needed to decrypt the values

Comment: To expand on my comment above; if you're defending against a root SQL breach then you can store the keys somwhere in a private backend of the server, if you're defending against a crazy web admin who has MySQL privileges then you may want to invest in SSH communication with a 3rd party key-store server. etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, i'll check the 3rd party key-store server for this.